# Automatic Site Creation

Tags: scripting, automation, automated-install

I have created a platform that i want users to sign up and a new site is created for them instantly. Users will register and afterwards they will receive a username and password for their personal site.

The system will work like ecommerce platforms such as www.shopify.com, www.bigcommerce.com, etc.. where users sign up and a new web-shop is created for them instantly.

I have been searching for a while for tools to automate this task but couldn't find any thing since i don't know their names.  Am using LAMP (Linux, Apache, MySql and PHP).

Am asking if someone know some names of such tools that i can use for site creation automation. When users sign up, a new site will be created for them. So am looking for such tools to automate the instant site creation.

Sorry if this place is wrong for this question.

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If by "a new site" you mean "a new Apache virtual host where the user can drop its contents", this can be automated quite easily.

But if instead (as I'm strongly guessing) you mean "a fully working website based on some template which the user can then further customize", then you're looking at something *quite* more complex than "some script" you can find in "a tutorial or a book or probably similar scripts".

Comment: i DON'T mean "a new Apache Virtual host" but rather "a fully working website based on some template which the user can then further customize".  It  is that tutorial/Script/book am looking for right now.

Comment: I fear no "tutorial/script/book" is going to help you building such a system from scratch, sorry.

Comment: this question don't need to be closed. It is a simple question and i know there are some tools/scripts out there to do such things. There are thousands of subscriptions web sites that users sign up and a new admin dashboard is generated for them to manage their own accounts. Am looking for such similar script on how to automate such tasks. There is nothing ambiguous about the question. It is simple and clear. If you don't know the answer or don't understand it clearly don't close it. Others can answer it. For the fact that you don't understand it doesn't mean you close the question.

Comment: For instance when a user signs up a new database, his home directory and all necessary folders are created for him automatically as well as copying all template files to his template folder, etc. I know this is a simple script that will do this work. It is not a huge thing that you guys think.

Comment: These things are **NOT** "a simple script", they are complex site management systems which are *way beyond* the scope of a tutorial. And if you don't understand this, and why things are this way, then you are in no position to manage such a system, yet alone to develop your own one.

Comment: if that is the case then i have edited the post

Comment: Ok, this is way better and someone will probably be able to provide you with at least a couple suggestions about already-existing software you can use for the job. However, you should ask this in a new question, as this one is closed now and it's probably not going to be reopened.